# How to I add a standalone month to a standalone year in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, dateadd, getdate

I need to make a SQL script return the same day and month but different with a different year for each year.

I have tried to use `DATEADD` to add the month and day to a standalone year that is in the form of `YEAR(GETDATE())`.

```
SELECT DATEADD(MM, 4, DATEADD(DD, 1, YEAR(GETDATE())))
```

When I run this it is returning  `1905-11-14 00:00:00.000` even when I replace the `GETDATE()` with an actual date, the `DATEADD()`'s are definitely working as when I change the numbers inside of them the output changes correspondingly.

--Edit--

The desired output I need from it is for the month and day to stay constantly at mm= 04 and dd= 01, however I need the year to be equal to the current year that it is being run.

So basically like this:

(Current year)-04-01

Comment: I don't understand what you want your output to look like. Sample data would help here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server, you can use `datefromparts()`:

```
select datefromparts(1950, month(getdate()), day(getdate())
```

or, add a number of years from the current year:

```
select dateadd(year, -4, convert(date, getdate()))
```

These might have slightly different behavior for leap days, but you would need to specify what you want to happen on that day.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add 4 months and 1 day to GetDate(), try this:

select DATEADD(MM, 4,  DATEADD(DD, 1, GETDATE() ))

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting the output you are is because of the way that `DATEADD` interprets integers.

The third argument for `DATEADD` should be a full date, but as written it's extracting the `YEAR` value of `GETDATE()`, which is currently 2019. `DATEADD` is treating that number as two thousand and nineteen days since "day 0". Day 0, under the hood, is `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000`, and 2019 days later is `1905-07-13 00:00:00.000`. Your inner `DATEADD` is adding one day to that, to take you to July 14th, and then your outer `DATEADD` is adding four months, resulting in the `1905-11-14 00:00:00.000` that you're seeing.

If all you're interested in doing is shifting the year, you can just use:

```
SELECT DATEADD(YEAR,<Whatever your offset value or values are>,GETDATE());
```

To get, say, the next five years worth:

```
SELECT DATEADD(YEAR,X,GETDATE()) AS NextFive
FROM
  (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5)) AS y(X);
```

Results:

```
+-------------------------+
|        NextFive         |
+-------------------------+
| 2020-06-04 14:07:56.800 |
| 2021-06-04 14:07:56.800 |
| 2022-06-04 14:07:56.800 |
| 2023-06-04 14:07:56.800 |
| 2024-06-04 14:07:56.800 |
+-------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out how to do it,

I took a past year, '1900-01-01', and them simply did a DATEDIFF() to return the number of years since that date:

```
DATEDIFF(YY, '1900-04-01', GETDATE())
```

Using this I could then add the result to the constant year '1900' plus my desired constant month (04) and day (01) (so '1900-04-01') to produce my desired result, this is easily done by putting the constant date in a DATEADD() statement with the DATEDIFF() statement above:

```
SELECT DATEADD(YY, DATEDIFF(YY, '1900-04-01', GETDATE()), '1900-04-01')
```

This then produces the result of:

```
2019-04-01 00:00:00.000
```

Where 2019 is the current year that the script is being run produced by the GETDATE() statement, and 04-01 is the desired month and day that the output should always be.